# .htaccess domain redirect not redirecting is accessed via invalid https

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

Does anyone know what needs adjusting to my rewrite rules in order to fix the issue I am facing, I am sure it is possible but tried a few things without success.

Current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^testsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.testsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.testsite\.co\.uk\/" [R=301,L]
```

The Issue:

For example, if I navigated to testsite.com, www.testsite.com it redirects fine to the https://www.testsite.co.uk/ however if I try the .com forcing SSL like https://testsite.com or https://www.testsite.com, for example, it shows SSL error as no SSL for that domain and does not redirect.

Expected:

If https is used on the pre-redirect domain should just redirect to the .co.uk domain

```
https://www.testsite.com > https://www.testsite.co.uk
https://testsite.com > https://www.testsite.co.uk
http://www.testsite.com > https://www.testsite.co.uk
http://testsite.com > https://www.testsite.co.uk
```

I should mention that the main site is the co.uk with a valid ssl and the .com is addon domain that points to co.uk

Comment: Is SSL cert valid for .com domain names?

Comment: Nope the SSL is only valid on co.uk, http on .com redirects fine to https co.uk but it you try https on .com fails of course but must be a way to redirect that to the correct site url which does have the certificate no?

Comment: No, you need a valid cert if you want to do anything https (even if only to redirect)

Comment: Ahh ok that sucks but makes sense, assumed would be the case but worth asking others before doing that. I guess just need a basic SSL here as will only handle a re-direction and not an EV cert like the main site. Thanks for your help mate